# When is `string.swapcase().swapcase()` not equal to `string`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, character-encoding, character

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) for str.swapcase() method says:

> Return a copy of the string with uppercase characters converted to lowercase and vice versa. **Note that it is not necessarily true that s.swapcase().swapcase() == s**.

I can't think of an example where `s.swapcase().swapcase() != s`, can anyone think of one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple example would be:

```
s = "ß"

print(s.swapcase().swapcase())
```

> Ouput:
>
> ```
> ss
> ```

[`ß` is German lowercase double s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F) (The "correct" uppercase version would be [`ẞ`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E)). The reason this happens is that the [Unicode standard](http://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt) has defined the capitalization of `ß` to be `SS`:

> ```
> The data in this file, combined with
> # the simple case mappings in UnicodeData.txt, defines the full case mappings
> # Lowercase_Mapping (lc), Titlecase_Mapping (tc), and Uppercase_Mapping (uc).
>
> ...
>
> # The entries in this file are in the following machine-readable format:
> #
> # <code>; <lower>; <title>; <upper>; (<condition_list>;)? # <comment>
>
> ...
>
> # The German es-zed is special--the normal mapping is to SS.
> # Note: the titlecase should never occur in practice. It is equal to titlecase(uppercase(<es-zed>))
>
> 00DF; 00DF; 0053 0073; 0053 0053; # LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S
> ```

(`00DF` is `ß`, `0053` is `S`, and `0073` is `s`)

Comment: Would you happen to know why is that so? What is the lowercase or uppercase of ```"ß"```? It's not clear to me, why the output is ss for this?

Comment: My favorite example for countering one's intuition about how case world's is the Turkish capital I with dot and the lowercase dotless i. Try `s = 'ıİ'` and see what happens.

Comment: The "ß" to "ss" mapping is defined by the Unicode Consortium - see ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt.  Python isn't "knowing" or "deciding" anything, it's implementing the standard.  Python bundles a copy of the Unicode database in each release, and looks up character info in that db; Python does not make independent decisions about case-mappings etc.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, there is a wide range of examples: it happens with some greek symbols, german symbols, armenian symbols, and other specific/special symbols.

To get them all:

```
find_dif = lambda s: s.swapcase().swapcase() != s

[chr(s) for s in range(100000) if find_dif(chr(s))]
```

and you get:

> ['µ',
>    'ß',
>    'İ',
>    'ı',
>    'ŉ',
>    'ſ',
>    'ǰ',
>    'ͅ',
>    'ΐ',
>    'ΰ',
>    'ς',
>    'ϐ',
>    'ϑ',
>    'ϕ',
>    'ϖ',
>    'ϰ',
>    'ϱ',
>    'ϴ',
>    'ϵ',
>    'և',
>    'ᲀ',
>    'ᲁ',
>    'ᲂ',
>    'ᲃ',
>    'ᲄ',
>    'ᲅ',
>    'ᲆ',
>    'ᲇ',
>    'ᲈ',
>    'ẖ',
>    'ẗ',
>    'ẘ',
>    'ẙ',
>    'ẚ',
>    'ẛ',
>    'ẞ',
>    'ὐ',
>    'ὒ',
>    'ὔ',
>    'ὖ',
>    'ᾀ',
>    'ᾁ',
>    'ᾂ',
>    'ᾃ',
>    'ᾄ',
>    'ᾅ',
>    'ᾆ',
>    'ᾇ',
>    'ᾐ',
>    'ᾑ',
>    'ᾒ',
>    'ᾓ',
>    'ᾔ',
>    'ᾕ',
>    'ᾖ',
>    'ᾗ',
>    'ᾠ',
>    'ᾡ',
>    'ᾢ',
>    'ᾣ',
>    'ᾤ',
>    'ᾥ',
>    'ᾦ',
>    'ᾧ',
>    'ᾲ',
>    'ᾳ',
>    'ᾴ',
>    'ᾶ',
>    'ᾷ',
>    'ι',
>    'ῂ',
>    'ῃ',
>    'ῄ',
>    'ῆ',
>    'ῇ',
>    'ῒ',
>    'ΐ',
>    'ῖ',
>    'ῗ',
>    'ῢ',
>    'ΰ',
>    'ῤ',
>    'ῦ',
>    'ῧ',
>    'ῲ',
>    'ῳ',
>    'ῴ',
>    'ῶ',
>    'ῷ',
>    'Ω',
>    'K',
>    'Å',
>    'ﬀ',
>    'ﬁ',
>    'ﬂ',
>    'ﬃ',
>    'ﬄ',
>    'ﬅ',
>    'ﬆ',
>    'ﬓ',
>    'ﬔ',
>    'ﬕ',
>    'ﬖ',
>    'ﬗ']

Let's check them out:

```py
s1 = 'µ'
s2 = s1.swapcase().swapcase()

s1 == s2
```

> False

```py
s1 = 'ß'
s2 = s1.swapcase().swapcase()

s1 == s2
```

> False

```
s1 = 'ﬗ'
s2 = s1.swapcase().swapcase()

s1 == s2
```

> False